# Check Root Email on Laptop Running Ubuntu and Webmin

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, webmin

I am on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 running Webmin 1.998, Postfix 9.4.1, Thunderbird 91.11.

How can I use Thunderbird to read my root / webmin emails?

Researching this, I can only find an old post whose solutions all seem out-dated, due to changes in Thunderbird:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/2261/how-are-administrators-supposed-to-read-roots-mail

Things I tried:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1390751/426818

I installed  `sudo apt install mailutils-imap4d # IMAP` rebooted and configured TB accordingly.  All I get is `TB unable to connect server` error message.

**Update**

I have created `/.forward` containing `user@localhost` and in my `/etc/aliases` file, I have

```
postmaster:    root
root:   user
```

TB still refuses to connect `user@localhost`

Any tips?

Comment: Move the emails to your user maildir (and change perms if required)?  Set forwarding from root -> your user for future emails?

Comment: @davidgo thanks for the tip.  Not have any luck with this.  Its seems to be more difficult to read toot mail on my laptop, than my web servers.. go figure :-0